# Is there a way on Google Sheets to save an array in a single cell and use index to find the values of the matrix?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a matrix in the following format that I have created only using arrayformula and then it expands to give me the following output:

**Example:**

[image: Example]

I would like to know if it is possible to save all this data in only one cell and just find the values that I want using an index. So basically my idea is to only do something like index(matrix,2,3) but not having to expand my matrix to all the values that I have, but rather just saving all the data in only 1 cell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

insert your arrayformula into `INDEX` like:

```
=INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(...), 2, 3)
```